# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: mes no válido

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-12c

Hola buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema tengo un procedimiento en oracle el cual realiza una consulta, dentro los parámetros de entrada que se pasan uno es de tipo DATE que es el que me causa el error.

Servicio en java que llama el procedimiento:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("PC_PRUEBA");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(9, Date.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter(9, filtros.getFecha());
```

Procedimiento:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PC_PRUEBA (
  P_FECHA      IN DATE
, RESULTS               OUT INTEGER
, CUR_RESULTADO         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  p_testproc DATE;
BEGIN

    p_testproc := TO_DATE((P_FECHA),'dd/mm/yyyy');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('p_testproc: [' || p_testproc || ']');


  SQLWHERE := 'WHERE 1=1 '
  || CASE WHEN P_FECHA IS NOT NULL THEN  'AND A.FECHA = ' || p_testproc ELSE ' ' END
```

El error que me marca es:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "AGO": identificador no válido
```

He intentado usar **TO_CHAR** pero me marca que el mes no es válido:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: mes no válido
```

La versión de Oracle que utilizo es la 12.

Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este error, muchas gracias.

Comment: has probado definiendo DD/MM/YYYY (mayuscula)

Comment: Gracias por responder si ya lo había probado así y lo probé nuevamente y el mismo error. Saludos!!

Comment: y el parametro filtros.getFecha() que formato lleva?

Comment: este SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")  lo he modificado también pero al final la salida del DATE() es  Wed Aug 22 00:00:00 CDT 2012,  he intentado de mandarlo en cadena pero al convertirlo en DATE en el procedimiento vuelve a salir el mismo error